# "no module named cv2" after installing opencv3.4.0 successfully

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv3.4.0 as a non-root user in server, and I abided the https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html to install opencv, because I don't want to mix this edition with the other in root user, in `Cmake` I used these command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/zouyiping/software/opencv -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-3.4.0/modules -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/zouyiping/software/python3.6.4/bin/python3  -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D BUILD_TIFF=ON
```

where I'm sure that the path in `-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE` is exactly the output of `print(sys.executable)`.
Finally I got `3.4.0` when I put `pkg-config --modversion opencv`, and I tested a sample and it worked. So I believed that the opencv3.4.0 has been installed successfully, however, when I put `import cv2` in python, I got`no module named cv2`.
It doesn't make sense. I'm new to opencv, what should I do to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to install it separately ?

Comment: Try installing it with pip `pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: @ Miika Vuorio I have tried this but I found that `cv2.__version__` would show another version like `4.1.0` while the opencv I installed is `3.4.0`, so I wonder if that would be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install OpenCV**

Refresh the packages index and install the OpenCV package by typing:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

The command above will install all packages necessary to run OpenCV.

**Verify the OpenCV installation**

To verify the installation we will import the cv2 module and print the OpenCV version:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
```

**Output**

```
3.2.0
```